# Inserting a null value into SQL if form field blank

Tags: php, sql, null

I'm trying to add a null value into a database if the form field is left blank but not getting much luck...

Can anyone see where this is going wrong??

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("ipaddress","user","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

if (is_null($_POST["event_sub"]) || $_POST["event_sub"]=="") {
    $event_sub = NULL;
} else {
    $event_sub = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["event_sub"]);
}

$sql="INSERT INTO myTable (event_sub)
VALUES
(". $event_sub .")";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: Dump `$_POST` and `$sql`. The problem should become more evident then.

Comment: _"but not getting much luck [...] Can anyone see"_ Yeah, you. Output the query, look at errors you get from MySQL, check the data in the database.

Comment: Have you tried to set `$event_sub = "null"` ?

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm pretty new to PHP so forgive my naivety. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Tom yes, it might take some experience to see the problem solely by looking at the code, but by proper debugging you can come to the same conclusion. Not only will that result in a better question, it might even give you the solution without having to post the question, because you'll see the problem for yourself. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try this:

```
if (is_null($_POST["event_sub"]) || $_POST["event_sub"]=="") {
$event_sub = 'NULL';
} else {
$event_sub = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["event_sub"]);
}
```

Putting the NULL in single quotes will result in the word NULL being inserted into your query rather than an actual NULL, which is nothing.

Comment: @Tom Are you sure it didn't insert the text "NULL" rather than an actual NULL value?

Answer (score 0):

why would you need to search for the word NULL? Just leave the insert for that column blank. and make sure allow null is set in the table..